# Characteristic Function as Fourier Multiplier

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In lecture notes I have, it is mentioned that the characteristic function $\chi_I$ of an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is an $L^p$ Fourier multiplier for $1 < p < \infty$. 
I thought this would be easy to check, but I'm simply not seeing it.

I need to show that for any Schwartz  $f$, we have 
$$ \| \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\chi_I \mathcal{F}f] \|_p \leq C||f||_p.$$
Since $f \in \mathcal{S}$, there's nothing too strange happening here -- the transforms are still functions.

Using duality, density, and the Fourier multiplication formula, it suffices to show that

$$ \left| \int_I [\mathcal{F}f(\xi)]\; [\mathcal{F}^{-1}g(\xi)] \; d\xi \right| \leq C \|f\|_p\|g\|_{p'}$$
for any $g \in \mathcal{S}$, where $p'$ is the Holder conjugate of $p$. 
I don't know how to show this though. Any guidance would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to go via the Hilbert Transform $H$, whose multiplier is some multiple of $i(I_{(0,\infty)} - I_{(-\infty,0)})$.  The $L^p$ boundedness of the Hilbert transform was proved by M. Riesz Theorem, and it was considered quite a breakthrough when it was first proven.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Hilbert transform and its boundedness, but I don't see how that helps. Can I transform the Hilbert multiplier somehow to get the char. function of an arbitrary interval?

Comment: Think about what multiplier represents $T = M_{-\alpha} H M_\alpha$, where $M_\alpha f(x) = e^{i\alpha x} f(x) $.