# Partial sums of $L_p$ functions are $L_p$ functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

For $f\in L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ($1\leq p\leq 2$) define $S_Rf$ by $$S_Rf(x)=\int_{|\xi|<R}\hat f(\xi)e^{2\pi i\xi.x}d\xi$$
Since for $f\in L_p$ we have $\hat f\in L_{p'}$ (Hausdorff-Young inequality), and $\chi_{B_R}\in L_p$, the above integrals exist. I was wondering whether the fact that $S_Rf\in L_p$ can be proved trivially and I'm just missing it somehow. I can prove $S_R\phi\in L_p$ for each Schwartz space function $\phi$ using the smoothness of $\phi$ to integrate by parts. But for a general $f\in L_p$ I don't know. Any help would be appreciated.

I could apply convolution theorem and Young's convolution inequality, but I wanted to know if there are simpler ways to prove it.

Comment: This is not true unless $p=2$ or $n=1$. Search for "Fefferman disk multiplier".

Comment: @PhoemueX I know that only for $p=2$ the $S_R$ operators are bounded. But does it also say that the images are in $L_p$ only for $p=2$?

Comment: This follows from the closed graph theorem once you know the other fact.

Comment: @PhoemueX I see. And what about for $n=1$? I tried applying Young's inequality- I wrote $S_Rf=D_R*f$ where $D_R$ is the Dirichlet kernel. To get $1/p+1/q=1/p+1$ I must have $q=1$. But the Dirichlet kernel is in all $L_q$ except when $q=1$. How do I proceed then?

Comment: This case is not trivial at all. See for instance here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748973/characteristic-function-as-fourier-multiplier) for some pointers.